# Почему не работает z-index в Slick-slider?

Tags: css3, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здравствуйте! Есть `slick-slider в bootstrap`. Но, ни в этом суть. Обратите внимание на `after-before` в виде треугольника справа в ***превью слайдера***. Не удается сверстать таким образом, чтобы `z-index` этого `after-before` был выше `z-index` страницы. `Div` ***превью*** состоит из `3-х div`.

```html
<div class="slider-nav">
      <div class="slider-nav-1"><img alt="" src="images/Banner/Slider/Monitor-mini.png"></div>
      <div class="slider-nav-2"><img alt="" src="images/Banner/Slider/Tablet-mini.png"></div>
      <div class="slider-nav-3"><img alt="" src="images/Banner/Slider/Iphone-mini.png"></div>
  </div>
```

И, если я `after-before` вписываю в этот родительский `slider-nav`, то все работает. Если я его вписываю в любой другой `div` страницы, тоже работает. Но, когда я вписываю его в `slider-nav-1`, `slider-nav-2`, `slider-nav-3`, то `z-index after-before` выше только своего родителя. Но, если вынести его за пределы родителя, псевдоэлемент становится невидимым. Если данный код я набираю в `JSFiddle`, все работает. Пробовал устанавливать `z-index after-before` намного выше остальных элементов, пробовал для остальных слоев ставить `opacity` намного ниже. Может быть, все - таки, ***Slick*** создает такие наслоения? Тогда, как решить эту проблему? Спасибо!

Comment: просто поместите родительский блок (с after before ) выше и всё

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, выше в HTML-коде? Пробовал.